# Local connection is fine, but when I deploy it to a remote server nothing happens

Tags: php, xampp, require-once, dbase

I have a virtual shared server through:

- Godaddy
- Plesk 11.0
- Dreamweaver CS5
- phpMyAdmin through Plesk.

I use `XAMPP` for my local server and all is great! I can connect locally and I also can connect to the phpMyAdmin dbase file via `Dreamweaver`. It's just when I upload the file to my remote server I get:

```
Warning: require_once(Connections/TestConn.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\directory420.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 1
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Connections/TestConn.php' (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\directory420.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 1
```

I want my PHP registration form to be accessible to people that navigate to the page. I use `XAMPP` so I don't know why the Inetpub and vhost info shows up.

Comment: PLEASE STOP WRITING TITLE IN ALL CAPITAL..... With that out, it feels great! Now let me read the question.

Comment: check the folder structure on server, have you put your TextConn.php file into Connections folder?

Comment: Check the file permissions on the server; it should be readable for all (e.g. `rwxr--r--`)

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths. You can use configuration files for this. Make a file named `configuration.php,` put it in some common location like `DOCUMENT_ROOT/configutation.php`. Add the absolute paths to this like

```
define('LIBRARY_ROOT','c:\xx\yy\');
define('CONNECTION_ROOT','c:\xx\yy\ZZZ');
.
.
define('GG.....
```

Use this constants in your code. Import the configuration file in the flow root. Its easy when you move from server to server.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you but writing script isn't my best asset

Comment: Thank you for your time K. I found the problem. In Plesk under php setting for "open_basedir" was set to "none" and I changed it to "deflaut" and wala I can access my remote file. I will do a youtube video on this. Thanks